# Cloning a generator in perl (Coro::Generator package)

Tags: perl, iterator, clone, generator

I would like to clone a generator (Coro::Generator) state in Perl. For example: in the bellow code I have a generator which iterates over an array:

```
use Coro::Generator;
sub iterate_array {
    my @arr = @{ $_[0] };
    generator {
        foreach my $value (@arr) {
            # Each time function is called it returns the next value in the array
            yield $value;   
        }
        yield undef;
    };
}     

my @a = (1,2,3,4);
my $iterator = iterate_array(\@a);

print $iterator->();  # output: 1
```

So the output is 1. If called again it will be 2 (2nd item in array).

I now want to clone the state of the iterator. Something like:

```
my $clone = clone($iterator);          # Clone iterator
print $iterator->();                   # output: 2
print $clone->();                      # output: 2
```

Both $clone and $iterator produce the same results as they are clones of eachother.

I have tried using the Storable package, i.e.:

```
use Storable 'dclone';
my $clone = dclone($iterator);
```

But this gives an error:

```
Can't store CODE items at ...
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `Coro::Generator` module doesn't anticipate cloning an iterator:

1. The module itself has a rather hackish feel
2. Calculating the next generated item might have side effects. It is therefore not generally possible to “split” the iterator.

However, we can do this “cloning” ourself by *caching* the results of the iterator:

```
sub clone_iter {
    my ($n, $iter) = @_;
    my @caches;

    my $make_subiterator = sub {
        # each subiterator has its own cache of not-yet seen items
        my $cache = [];
        push @caches, $cache;
        return sub {
            # If *our* cache is empty…
            if (not @$cache) {
                my $result = $iter->();
                # add this result to *all* caches
                push @$_, \$result for @caches;
            }
            return ${ shift @$cache };
        };
    };

    return map { $make_subiterator->() } 1 .. $n;
}

my $i = 1;
my $iter = sub { $i++ }; # just for testing
my ($iter_a, $iter_b, $iter_c) = clone_iter(3, $iter);
say join ' ', map { $iter_a->() } 1 ..  3;
say join ' ', map { $iter_b->() } 1 ..  7;
say join ' ', map { $iter_a->() } 4 .. 10;
say join ' ', map { $iter_c->() } 1 ..  7;
```

Sample output:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks. But this operation could be costly if the iterator takes a while to get back to the same position.